# How to contact a user about a dead link on their profile?

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page

I looked on a user's profile (who was active on SO), and followed the link to what looked from the URL like it would be their blog. It turned out to be a link-farm type squatted blog. The domain registration had clearly lapsed.

What would be the best way to contact this person to let them know that the URL on their profile isn't pointing to their blog anymore as (probably) intended? Pinging them on chat apparently doesn't work if they don't use chat. Would it be appropriate to leave a comment on one of their posts?

Comment: Make a meta post like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351671/how-to-contact-a-user-about-a-dead-link-on-their-profile?cb=1) and hope they see it and take the hint

Comment: @cat https://www.google.nl/search?q=recursion

Comment: *"Pinging them on chat apparently doesn't work if they don't use chat."* Figured this was about me, and dutifully checked my profile, just like cat suggested. No dead links in there, though!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, it would be appropriate to leave a comment on one of their posts. Be sure to delete / flag the comments as obsolete when the problem is fixed (or it becomes obvious that the user isn't around any more).